# Changing body color in articles Joomla

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

How can I change the body bg color to and specific article in Joomla?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Is it one article in particular you want to change the body of?  what 'body bg' color do want to change specifically?  The bg of the template?

Comment: Yes, I need to change the background of the web site on an specific article ..

Answer (score 0):

We accomplish exactly this for a scientific site by specifying the `Page Class Suffix` when creating a menu item for the article.  It's located on the menu option page under `Parameters (System)`, and whatever string you put in there is appended to the class of the page.  From there, your CSS skills and Firebug will be your friend to add your class and make changes in the appropriate CSS files.